# WinMobile устройства. Настройка сети по IP. Работа 2 и более устройств с компьютером одновременно.

Tags: сеть

Cтолкнулся с проблемой подключения к сети 2 и более устройств одновременно.

Устройство отправляет запрос на локальный компьютер по IP. Есть программа ActiveSync которая помогает соединить 1 устройство, но одновременно с несколькими она не работает. Как я подозреваю, можно выставить где-то в настройках строгий IP, но как это сделать, не знаю, так как вроде даже и получается, но результата нет. Если кто разбирался, помогите пожалуйста сконфигурировать сеть.

Ps. может Windows Mobile Device Center поддерживает несколько устройств одновременно, но я не могу проверить, даже Google об этом чего-то молчит. Наверняка нет поддержки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveSync - это для синхронизации данных в Винмобайле и, скажем, Аутлуке. Там - да, только один девайс! Насчёт WM Device Center тоже не уверен, что несколько одновременно. Поочерёдно - можно, с разными профайлами. Но что нужно-то? Если просто подключение к сети, а не синхронизация, то должен быть роутер, который этим управляет, и TCP/IP подключение к нему (например, через WiFi). Насколько мне известно, ни ActiveSync, ни Windows Mobile Device Center шлюзами TCP/IP не являются!

Comment: спасибо за информацию. Действительно после всех разбирательств я решил проблему подключением через wi-fi, хотя если бы у меня был роутер или переходник какой-то там, то аналогично устройства получили бы свои IP и работали с компом.

Answer (score 0):

Если не ошибаюсь, ActiveSync поддерживает одновременно только одно устройство...
А Windows Mobile Device Center работает с устройствами WM версией выше 6.х

Comment: Поправлю - с версии WM 2003 (пруфлинк от Майкрософт: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/931937/ru)

Comment: Да, точно, спасибо за уточнение...